# Why does the query display each letter of the first match?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In `Owner` I have properties `"owner"` and `"owner_tag"`.

I query by `owner` and then try to print `owner_tag` for matching results. But what I get is each letter of the first match of `owner_tag`:

So, in `Owner`

owner: az@example.com has owner_tag: `tag1, tag2, tag3`.

The query matches `"tag1"` and loops through `"t"`, `"a"`, `"g"`, `"1"`. I don't understand why?

Here is the code:

```
query = Owner.all()
query.filter("owner", user)
w = query.get()

for tag in w.owner_tag:
    self.response.out.write("""
    %s, %s""" %
    (tag, w.tag_value))
```

**Update**

If I use `fetch()` instead of `get()` then it works. But since I don't know the number of items to fetch, how do I get them all without specifying a number. I thought that `get()` fetched all matching items:

```
query = Owner.all()
query.filter("owner", user)
w = query.fetch(10)

for tag in w:
    self.response.out.write("""
    %s, %s""" %
    (tag.owner_tag, tag.tag_value))
```

Can you explain why the above works and the original code with `get()` does not work?

Comment: Does the query return a collection of strings or just a single string?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: How do I check that? `logging.info` for `w` tells me only that it is w: <__main__.Owner object at 0x05F10870.

Comment: `get` returns a single result. `fetch` returns an array of results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_get) always returns a single result or `None`, and when you iterate over a single string, each value's a character.  [`fetch()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch) works the way you think, with an optional `offset` argument so you can page through the results if you want to.

`fetch()` makes sense if there are potentially tons of results that you might not want to pay for retrieving, or if you want to get a specific number of results in one trip to the datastore.

If you want all results and don't mind leaving it to appengine to decide how many round trips to retrieve them in, you can just iterate over the query: `for tag in query.filter("owner", user)`.